# Getting values from Object, putting them in one array separated by commas

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, join, input

Recently I asked a similar question but I will delete it because it was not clear enough, my bad.

I need to get year, month and date values from multiple dynamic objects

```
Object {year: 2017, month: 1, date: 26}    
Object {year: 2017, month: 2, date: 5}
Object {year: 2017, month: 2, date: 12}
Object {year: 2017, month: 2, date: 19}
Object {year: 2017, month: 2, date: 26}
```

and I need to make them in array like this:

```
[26/1/2017, 5/2/2017, 12/2/2017, 19/2/2017, 26/2/2017]
```

and than, use that array to put these values in input hidden value like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="26/1/2017, 5/2/2017, 12/2/2017, 19/2/2017, 26/2/2017">
```

I managed to get the values and push them in arrays but I can't get them to work as it should, here is my code:

```
           // Note: This code is in each function

            // This holds the objects
            var sundayData = $(this).data();

            // I get date, month and year values
            var dayAll = sundayData['date'];
            var monthAll = sundayData['month'];
            var yearAll = sundayData['year'];

            // Here, I putting them in the right format
            var sundayDatesAll = dayAll + '/' + (monthAll + 1) + '/' + yearAll;
            //
            var sundayDate = [];

            // Here, I push the dates in sundayDate
            sundayDate.push(sundayDatesAll);

            $('input').val(sundayDate.join());
```

But, like this, it returns separated arrays like this:

```
["26/2/2017"]
["5/3/2017"]
["12/3/2017"]
["19/3/2017"]
["26/3/2017"]
```

and there is only one value in the input, i think its the last value 26/3/2017

Any help is appreciated, thanks...

Comment: use concat() method to merge the arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the old value of the input, split it, then add the new date to it, rather than starting with an empty array each time.

```
var sundayDate = $('input').val().split(',');
// Here, I push the dates in sundayDate
sundayDate.push(sundayDatesAll);
$('input').val(sundayDate.join(','));
```

You can combine this into:

```
$('input').val(function(i, oldDates) {
    var sundayDate = oldDates.split(',');
    sundayDate.push(sundayDatesAll);
    return sundayDate.join(',');
});
```